# Android java: using Firebase to post data whenever there is a signal

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to find a clever way of "http posting" a worker thread of client device queue'd worker jobs but only when the signal is good. The reason for this is that just repeat repeat server pushing is sub optimal: The battery does not need taxing and the files are large image files or video.

The app is for diagnostic use in server rooms, often hardened with concrete walls, with hard to reach locations until "the user" leaves the site.

I read somewhere that firebase can "hold" jobs and dispatch them. We currently use do use Firebase, but currently only as a server push event listener. Is there a way to "dispatch" a post to firebase and for firebase to queue it?

I appreciate I am probably just missing the "***proper name***" for what  I want to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is probably not going to help much in terms of providing a generic queue of work to be executed some time later.  You should look into using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), which lets you add items of work to be executed later, under the [conditions you specify](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work), including having network access.